Проверка орфографии на веб странице. Подсветка ошибок
Как сделать чтобы при загрузке веб страницы выполнялась проверка орфографии и подчеркивались слова с ошибками.
На странице расположен простой текст и предзаполненные поля textarea.
Желательно чтобы выполнялась проверка всего текста на странице, а не только textarea.
В textarea - проверка грамматики выполняется только при фокусировке на поле. И никакие теги и css не помогают выполнить проверку сразу при загрузке страницы.
Буду благодарен за любое решение от плагинов до css, js...
Мне необходимо это реализовать для своей страницы

